# Executing an .exe file along command line arguments in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line-arguments

I am using two projects in Visual Studio and I want to execute/run an .exe file with command line arguments.

Variables I want to use as command line arguments:

```
    float OneXa = Line1.a.XHnit; // argument 1
    float OneYa = Line1.a.YHnit; // argument 2
    float OneXb = Line1.b.XHnit; // argument 3
    float OneYb = Line1.b.YHnit; // argument 4

    float TwoXa = Line2.a.XHnit; // argument 5
    float TwoYa = Line2.a.YHnit; // argument 6
    float TwoXb = Line2.b.XHnit; // argument 7
    float TwoYb = Line2.b.YHnit; // argument 8
```

The executing command along with the command line arguments. The .exe file executes, BUT the command line arguments are not passed along to the .exe file.I want to use variables as arguments, or at least their values. **That is my problem here.**

```
    system("Lokaverkefni3.exe OneXa OneYa OneXb OneYb TwoXa TwoYa TwoXb TwoYb"); // DOESN'T WORK
    system("Lokaverkefni3.exe 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 8"); // WORKS
```

Comment: not a single answer found? Do you know [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Launching+an+.exe+file+with+command+arguments+in+Visual+Studio&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Zl46VZWNG4PYauPqgFA)?

Comment: The system could not find your program in the `%PATH%`, you have some options here. You can add the output path of the project Lokaverkefni3 into the `%PATH%` variable ou you could set the output paht of both projects to the same directory.

Comment: Please add info for you troubleshooting to make your question clearer , other than that it will be guessing your exact problem to find a solution. 

Anyhow, have a look at this source and let me know if that support your issue:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/334c178b-7200-46aa-b9e2-80172e1b88dd/file-name-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: @DeJaVo I update the information, sorry for my bad english :S

Comment: The only solution I have found myself and works is to write the arguments in a .txt file, line by line, and then store those values in an array inside the scope of Lokaverkefni3.exe.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set the `Working Directory`, in the Debugging page of your project configuration, to the location of the `Lokaverkefni3.exe` file.

[image]

This way, your program will be executed in the specified directory, where it can find the 'Lokaverkefni3.exe` file.